# Announcer Badge Question

Tags: support, badges

I have read over the auto-populated questions (when I typed in the **Announcer Badge Questio**n title) and other documentation or help I can find and I have some questions specific to the **Announcer Badge** (see below) and exactly where it's allowed to be used to be applied accordingly.

If there is some obvious resource that goes over my questions about this topic, please let me know but I have looked around and some things are not too clear about this and how it works or what's required.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Can I share a link to a question in a SuperUser `comment`, which I post as a comment for others to click, and do applicable clicks work for this badge?
2. Can I share a link to a question in a SuperUser answer and/or question, and have those clicks from others in either of those also count for this? Meaning does it matter if it's something I post in an answer versus a question?
3. I've read some of the auto-populated ***similar*** questions when I put the title of my question here (this one you're reading), and I saw and read references there about sharing links to questions with external sources/sites, so I was curious if those clicks (posted links to SuperUser questions but posting these on other non-SO/SE sites) count too?
4. For #3 above, if this is applicable for ***everyone*** that clicks with a unique IP address does it count for ***both*** **registered and non-registered Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange / SuperUser accounts**.

Again, if there's something I missed that clarifies these questions, I'll be happy to review that as well but I'm hopeful the experts here that understand this can clarify this for me and potentially others in the future that find this information useful.

[image]

Hopefully I tagged this question appropriately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By default the links to comments don't include your user id, so it's not going to work. Can't say for sure if including user id tracks the views for a comment, but I'm guessing it should
2. Links are tracked from external sources - by external, anything outside of the Stack Exchange network
3. Like mentioned above, internal sources aren't counted
4. Registered/unregistered account status doesn't matter

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify real quick, when you say "links to comments don't include your user id", does that mean links to questions that I post as a comment will not include the userid for the tracking with the URL, etc.? It also sounds like you're saying if you put a comment with a link but manually put in your user id in that part of the URL, it MAY work?  Does this all sound correct to you? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Also, for my #2 question, it sounds like the user id part in the shared link URL will be applied by default for both answer and questions someone posts with a shared link to a question, correct? The only thing that may need to have the user id part added to the link URL for the click tracking would be a shared link on a comment someone would post?

Comment: I mean the link to your comment (hover on the timestamp) don't include your user id, but the share link which is present on question/answer, do. For tracking purpose only the user id is required. So yes, if you manually put in the user id, it *may* work for a comment - I  know it works for question/answer because that's how we used to share prior to the share link come into picture quite some time back